# Maintain and Release Ionic Framework v1 in 2023

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, legacy-code

I have an Ionic Framework v1 app that we just can't upgrade for complex reasons yet. With the latest API Level and SDK targets from Android and iOS, how can I get this app into the app stores in 2023?

I have tried updating the platforms to the latest versions but there are too many plugin mismatches. This is taking too long, so I wondered if someone out there has already solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very difficult. I would suggest to have a machine specifically to build and run this app ONLY. Reason being is because Ionic 1 requires old node and npm versions. If you cant use one machine then you need a package manager to switch between node/npm versions.These versions need to be specific to ionic 1, so you would need to find a list somewhere, and not sure if this can be found.

Long story short, you will be wasting lots and lots of time trying to maintain this app. Your best bet is just to create a new project in ionic 7 and move over the code from old project to this newly created project while at the same time refactoring your old code. Goodluck!